# Finding the convergence of moment generating function computed using integrals and series

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Given the exponential density function $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, the nth moment is $\mu_n=n!/\lambda^n$.

If using the series representation to find the moment generating function $g(t)$:

$$g(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu_kt^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{t}{\lambda} \right)^k=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$$

Which only converges if $|t|<\lambda$. However, finding $g(t)$ from integration:

$$g(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} = \left. \frac{\lambda e^{(t-\lambda)x}}{t-\lambda} \right|^\infty_0 =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$$

Which converges for $t < \lambda$ and appears to not have a lower bound. I'm wondering why there appears to be a difference in the region of $t$ in which the MGF converges for the same pdf, and which one is correct?

Comment: The definition of the moment generating function is $$\mathbb E[e^{tX}] = \int_0^\infty e^{tx} f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx. $$ So that is what you should be basing the region of convergence on.

Comment: @Math1000 My book defines the MGF in [two ways](https://imgur.com/a/Njst6UG) (as equivalents), is this not conventional? That excerpt is on [page 404](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf).

Comment: Sorry, the definition is
$$
\mathbb E[e^{tX}] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx,
$$
provided the integral converges. This is a more general definition because it allows you to define the moment generating function for distributions that do not have finite moments of all orders.